# Event-driven MVC application

Tags: events, design-patterns, hook

I have a MVC application which uses events(hooks) and I have a question about when to trigger an event.

There are three options:

- trigger in models(this approach will mess-up the code, but gain a little more flexibility)
- trigger in controllers(after or before calling some models)
- creating a new layer of abstraction between controllers and models that extends my models and trigger the event(decorator pattern)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third option - within your viewmodels or repository/unit of work implementations

Comment: Can you be more specify please? I don't understand what you mean with viewmodels or repository/unit of work...

Comment: You have a lot of reading to do, then; read up on the repository and unit of work patterns.  Also search for MVC with ViewModel.  After reading about these patterns, you should have a much better idea of how you want to go about solving your problem